# lines not cover by coverage report in python3 Flask, unittest and cntext.py in test directory

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

When I run the command `coverage report -m` after running `coverage run main.py` any of the lines in the methods that I have test are covered, I using a `context.py` file and I have the following project structure

```
my_project
├── service
│   ├── __init__.py        
│   └── setThings.py
└── test
    ├── context.py 
    ├── __init__.py         
    └── test_setThings.py
```

this is the content of my context.py

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import service
from service import setThings
```

This is my service setThings.py

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def check_if_json_property_is_null(json_property):
    if(json_property != ""):
        return json_property
    else:
        return "&nbsp"
```

and this is my test file

```
import unittest
import json
from collections import namedtuple

from .context import setThings

class Test_SetThings(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_given_none_property_when_checking_if_none_return_empty(self):
        #ASSERT
        self.assertEqual("&nbsp", setThings.check_if_json_property_is_null(""))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So after I run `coverage report -m` it says that the lines inside my service methods are not covered, I'm using 
coverage==4.5.3 in my requirements file,

Also I'm running all the commands from the project root

Comment: We usually use *coverage* to measure the code coverage of your library (here *service*, but not to measure the coverage of your test: it's a non-sense.

Comment: I edited my question I was referring to the lines of my service, the lines of my service are not being covered